# Calculating and displaying number statistics

Tags: java, array, statistics

I'm writing a program which takes individual int inputs from the user and then outputs some details on the numbers (average, min, max and how many).
`Input.readInt()` is a method I made which simply reads an integer from the command line and returns it.

There are a few things I'd like to improve - for the average the float does not seem to work, it only holds prints out value to nearest integer. I'd also like to format this to always display 2 decimal places.
Is there any way to dynamically assign the size of the array? So I could enter more than 10 values?

I'm looking for advice on more efficient methods (both speed and code length), and any other general advice which could help me learn.

```
public class NumberStats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = new int[10];
        int i;
        int total = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (true) { // READ INPUTS
            System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            input[count] = Input.readInt();

            if (input[count] == 0) {
                break;
            } else if (input[count] < 0) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + input[count]
                        + " is not valid, exiting.\n");
                break;
            } else if (input[count] > 100) {
                System.out
                        .println("Warning: "
                                + input[count]
                                + " is not valid and will be excluded from final statistics.");
            }

            if (input[count] <= 100) { // IF INPUT VALID
                if (count == 0) {
                    min = input[count];
                    max = input[count];
                } else if (input[count] < min) {
                    min = input[count];
                } else if (input[count] > max) {
                    max = input[count];
                }
                count++;
                System.out.println("#" + count + ": " + input[count - 1]);
            }

        }
        if (count != 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { // CALCULATE SUM
                total += input[i];
            }
            average = total / count; // CALCULATE AVERAGE

            System.out.println("Total: " + total);
            System.out.println("Count: " + count);
            System.out.println("Min: " + min);
            System.out.println("Max: " + max);
            System.out.println("Average: " + average);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No valid input");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please tell me this is for your personal benefit and that you aren't asking me to do your homework!

```
average = total / count;
```

`total` and `count` are both integers, so `/` performs integer division.  The result is then converted to a double.  This should fix your problem:

```
average = ((double) total) / ((double) count);
```

> Is there any way to dynamically assign the size of the array? so i
>   could if i wish enter more than 10 values?

Use a [java.util.ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
// old:
// int[] input = new int[10];
// new:
List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

> I'd also like to format this to always display 2 decimal places

Look at [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

## General Advice

You do an awful lot of typing and a lot of dereferencing (and typing!).  Declare a local `inVal` parameter:

```
int inVal = 0;
...

inVal = Input.readInt();
if (inVal < 0) {
    ...
}
// Finally, after all your checks and calculations, add inVal to your array (or List):
input[count] = inVal;
```

The point of most loop syntax is to make the exit conditions for the loop obvious.  Instead of `while (true)` I'd like to see something like:

```
do {
    ...
} while (inVal >= 0)
```

I like that you calculate your max and min in the input loop.  You could count your total in that loop as well  instead of taking a second loop through your data.  Hmm...  If you do that, you don't need to use an array or a List, just `inVal`.

You have "magic numbers" 0 and 100.  Years from now when three other programmers have worked on this code, they may add a percentage calculation as `x / 100` so that when you decide to increase your number of inputs to 200, you search-and-replace `100` with `200` you have broken your percentage calculation.  You should factor these out of your code:

```
public final int MAX_NUM_INPUTS = 100;
public final int INPUT_TOO_LOW_VALUE = 0;
```

This clarifies what you are comparing in a way that Magic Numbers could not:

```
if (count > MAX_NUM_INPUTS) ...

if (inVal <= INPUT_TOO_LOW_VALUE) ...
```

Hopefully no-one would ever calculate percent as `x / MAX_NUM_INPUTS`.  Now you can change these limits in one place without doing any search-and-replace.

**UPDATE:**

`System.out.println`...

Yeah, Java is funny about string concatenation.  If you have a non-final variable as part of a String, it can cause a bunch of nasty overhead.  For a little program like yours, it really doesn't matter what you do.  If it were going to print out a String in a loop, then I'd suggest the following change.  Note that `System.err.println()` uses an OS-specific line separator - not necessarily `\n`.

```
// This is fine for your program..
System.err.println("Error: " + input[count]
                        + " is not valid, exiting.\n");

// Option 1: Use multiple print stmts to avoid String concatenation:
System.err.print("Error: ");
System.err.print(inVal);
System.err.println(" is not valid; exiting.");
System.err.println();

// Option 2: Use a StringBuilder (also uses "method chaining" idiom):
System.err.println(new StringBuilder().append("Error: ")
                                      .append(inVal)
                                      .append(" is not valid; exiting.")
                                      .toString());
System.err.println();
```

This really isn't important in your specific example because it's so small.  In a bigger program or a production situation String concatenation can be a real performance problem.  People often make mistakes in logging code that really slows a system down.  I think later versions of Java have tamed this issue.  I know IntelliJ IDEA reports various times when it's better to use the + signs vs. a StringBuilder.  I've checked the compiled code a few times when I thought it was wrong, and it turned out to be right, so now I just trust it to tell me.

Comment: Haha no this is a personal learning exercise i'm doing.  thanks for the detailed advice and explanations, it helps alot!

Comment: Is it more acceptable to use system.out.println() repeatedly for the final out put or should I be using system.out.print and then format the string?

Answer (score 4):

Glen Peterson's advice is good, but there's something I'd like to add:

You're programming in Java, an **object-oriented** language. When first learning to program, it's often hard to imagine the practical value of using objects. Therefore, as a beginner one often ends up with a style similar to yours: all code is in a single class, and indeed within a single method in that class.

This style is called *monolithic* and although it has the benefit of being very concise, it leads to unmaintainable, hard-to-debug and unreadable code. As the requirements evolve in complexity, these problems become worse.

To *solve* them, first analyse the **responsibilities** of your code:

- Input/Output
- Validation
- Tracking statistics

These **concerns** should be handled by **collaborating objects**. For instance, to track statistics, you could create a `StatisticsTracker`:

```
public class StatisticsTracker {
    private int count;
    private int total;
    private int minimum;
    private int maximum;

    public void addNumber(int number) {
        count++;
        total += number;
        adjustMinimumAndMaximum(number);
    }

    private void adjustMinimumAndMaximum(int number) {
        if (containsSingleNumber()) {
            minimum = number;
            maximum = number;
        } else if (number < minimum) {
            minimum = number;
        } else if (number > maximum) {
            maximum = number;
        }
    }

    private boolean containsSingleNumber() {
        return count == 1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public int getMinimum() {
        return minimum;
    }

    public int getMaximum() {
        return maximum;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return (double) total / count;
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to hang on to an array or list of numbers; you can track the statistics as you add numbers. Please also note that all this code knows *nothing* about validation or input/output: all it cares about is tracking statistics.

Next, we'll need a collaborator that validates our input. Because I'm assuming your validation requirements are likely to change, it makes sense to define an *interface* (`T` means there can be validators for any type of data, such as strings, integers or floating-point numbers):

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    public ValidationResult validate(T input);
}
```

Our validator needs to check if the input is between two bounds, so let's implement the interface:

```
public class IntegerBoundsValidator implements Validator<Integer> {
    private int lower;
    private int upper;

    public IntegerBoundsValidator(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
        lower = lowerBound;
        upper = upperBound;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationResult validate(Integer input) {
        if (input < lower) {
            return ValidationResult.invalid("input must be greater than " + lower);
        }
        if (input > upper) {
            return ValidationResult.invalid("input must be smaller than " + upper);
        }
        return ValidationResult.valid();
    }
}
```

You'll notice the use of a class called `ValidationResult`. This is a **Value Type**. It has no significant behaviour; it just contains data and some static convenience methods to create instances of it, as seen below. Some OOP purists disagree with my use of `public final` fields; feel free to make them `private` and add getters if you so desire.

```
public class ValidationResult {
    public final boolean isValid;
    public final String message;

    private static final ValidationResult VALID = new ValidationResult(true, "");

    public static ValidationResult valid() {
        return VALID;
    }

    public static ValidationResult invalid(String message) {
        return new ValidationResult(false, message);
    }

    private ValidationResult(boolean isValid, String message) {
        this.isValid = isValid;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

To connect all these parts together, we'll use a class called `Main` - for the lack of a better name.

```
public class Main {
    private static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static final Validator<Integer> validator = new IntegerBoundsValidator(0, 100);
    private static final StatisticsTracker statistics = new StatisticsTracker();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            int next = input.nextInt();
            handleInput(next);
        }
        printStatistics();
    }

    public static void handleInput(int input) {
        ValidationResult result = validator.validate(input);
        if (result.isValid) {
            statistics.addNumber(input);
        } else {
            printLine(result.message);
        }
    }

    private static void printStatistics() {
        if (statistics.getCount() == 0){
            printLine("No valid input.");
            return;
        }
        printLine("Total: %d", statistics.getTotal());
        printLine("Count: %d", statistics.getCount());
        printLine("Min: %d", statistics.getMinimum());
        printLine("Max: %d", statistics.getMaximum());
        printLine("Average: %.2f", statistics.getAverage());
    }

    private static void printLine(String format, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(format, args));
    }
}
```

## Conclusion

Why go to all this effort of **refactoring**? Well, the benefits are apparent:

- Each class now fulfils a clearly-defined **responsibility**. Changes in one of those classes will not affect the other responsibilities.
- Each method within these classes is short and has a readable name. These methods can and should be tested separately with **unit tests**, which is close to impossible with  monolithic code.
- The system is **extensible**: It's easy to change your validation requirements by simply plugging in a different `Validator` instance. You could create a `CompositeValidator` that combines several validators into a single validator chain.

Of course, you may disagree with some of the implementation details — but this review isn't really about those. It's more of a demonstration of which questions you should be asking in order to end up with **clean code**.

Good luck with your learning, and thanks for sharing your code.